# Custom Table of contents with description in between

Tags: table-of-contents

Can someone please suggest me how to create this custom table of contents?

[image: Table of Contents]

[image: Table of Contents]

Comment: The TOC gets derived from the contents of the body of the document. Please provide an MWE (from `documentclass{...` to `\end{document}`) showing what you have done and that we can process. Do you use `\part`, `\chapter`, ...? How do you represent the unnumbered subheadings?  We could make guesses but why waste time when they might be very wrong.

Comment: @PeterWilson I haven't designed the document yet and I need suggestions on how can I achieve this in LaTeX. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.